# Limiting a field's value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

I am developing a program that uses a MySQL database to store data. I have a table (simplified here):

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| dataId  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| someNum | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now, I update the table with a query like this one.

```sql
UPDATE table SET someNum=someNum+2 WHERE dataId=78225;
```

The ID and the amount `someNum` changes come dynamically from code.

Now, what I'd like to do is limit `someNum`'s value to between -3 and 3, particularly in that `UPDATE`. It isn't required, my software can handle it being outside that range, but the data would be clearer with that limit. If `someNum+2` would be over 3, I'd just like to set it to 3.

Numeric `MIN`/`MAX` would make it easy:

```sql
UPDATE table SET someNum=MAX(-3,MIN(3,someNum+2)) WHERE dataId=78225;
```

I looked at the docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-functions.html), but there seems to be no `MIN`/`MAX` for numbers. `MIN` and `MAX` are found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), but they don't seem to be the right ones for this.

What would be the best way (if any) to implement such a limit in MySQL (*not* the code that calls MySQL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First way: use [`LEAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
UPDATE t SET someNum=GREATEST(-3,LEAST(3,someNum+2)) WHERE dataId=78225;
```

This is the most easy way because you'll store all the logic inside one `UPDATE` query.

Second way: create [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER catCheck BEFORE UPDATE ON t
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.someNum<-3 THEN
           NEW.someNum=-3;
        END IF;

        IF NEW.someNum>3 THEN
           NEW.someNum=3;
        END IF;
    END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

you can also replace `IF` with `CASE` - but I left that two separate constraints for `-3` and `3`. The benefits here is - that DBMS will handle your data by itself - and you'll be able to pass data as it is and do not worry about ranges. But - there's weakness too: while in first case you can just change query text to adjust desired range, in second case you'll have to re-create trigger again if you'll want to change that constraints (so, less flexibility).

Also you may want to check your data not only on `UPDATE` statements, but on `INSERT` too.

Answer (score 1):

use [GREATEST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) and [LEAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) instead of MAX and MIN

You could also use a CASE WHEN

```
update table
set someNum = CASE WHEN SomeNum +2 > 3 THEN 3 
                   WHEN SomeNum +2 < -3 THEN -3
                   ELSE someNum + 2
              END)
```

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate functions in MySQL are `greatest()` and `least()`, not `max()`/`min()`.  But, I think it is clearer with just a `case` statement:

```
UPDATE table
    SET someNum = (case when someNum + 2 < -3 then -3
                        when someNum + 2 > 3 then 3
                        else someNum + 2
                   end) 
   WHERE dataId=78225;
```